# PyMC3: Hierarchical rugby model posterior?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, mcmc, pymc3

I've just started reading through the [`PyMC3` documentation](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/index.html) (I'm much more comfortable with `sklearn`) and came across the [Rugby hierarchical model example](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/rugby_analytics.html):

```
# Imports and Rugby data setup -- model in next section

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

games = [
    ['Wales', 'Italy', 23, 15],
    ['France', 'England', 26, 24],
    ['Ireland', 'Scotland', 28, 6],
    ['Ireland', 'Wales', 26, 3],
    ['Scotland', 'England', 0, 20],
    ['France', 'Italy', 30, 10],
    ['Wales', 'France', 27, 6],
    ['Italy', 'Scotland', 20, 21],
    ['England', 'Ireland', 13, 10],
    ['Ireland', 'Italy', 46, 7],
    ['Scotland', 'France', 17, 19],
    ['England', 'Wales', 29, 18],
    ['Italy', 'England', 11, 52],
    ['Wales', 'Scotland', 51, 3],
    ['France', 'Ireland', 20, 22],
]
columns = ['home_team', 'away_team', 'home_score', 'away_score']
df = pd.DataFrame(games, columns=columns)

teams = df.home_team.unique()
teams = pd.DataFrame(teams, columns=['team'])
teams['i'] = teams.index

df = pd.merge(df, teams, left_on='home_team', right_on='team', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns = {'i': 'i_home'}).drop('team', 1)
df = pd.merge(df, teams, left_on='away_team', right_on='team', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns = {'i': 'i_away'}).drop('team', 1)

observed_home_goals = df.home_score.values
observed_away_goals = df.away_score.values

home_team = df.i_home.values
away_team = df.i_away.values

num_teams = len(df.i_home.drop_duplicates())
num_games = len(home_team)

g = df.groupby('i_away')
att_starting_points = np.log(g.away_score.mean())
g = df.groupby('i_home')
def_starting_points = -np.log(g.away_score.mean())
```

Here's the main `PyMC3` model setup:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Global model parameters
    home = pm.Normal('home', 0, tau=.0001)
    tau_att = pm.Gamma('tau_att', .1, .1)
    tau_def = pm.Gamma('tau_def', .1, .1)
    intercept = pm.Normal('intercept', 0, tau=.0001)

    # Team-specific model parameters
    atts_star = pm.Normal('atts_star', mu=0, tau=tau_att, shape=num_teams)
    defs_star = pm.Normal('defs_star', mu=0, tau=tau_def, shape=num_teams)

    atts = pm.Deterministic('atts', atts_star - tt.mean(atts_star))
    defs = pm.Deterministic('defs', defs_star - tt.mean(defs_star))
    home_theta = tt.exp(intercept + home + atts[home_team] + defs[away_team])
    away_theta = tt.exp(intercept + atts[away_team] + defs[home_team])

    # Likelihood of observed data
    home_points = pm.Poisson('home_points', mu=home_theta, observed=observed_home_goals)
    away_points = pm.Poisson('away_points', mu=away_theta, observed=observed_away_goals)

    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.NUTS(state=start)
    trace = pm.sample(20000, step, init=start)
```

I know how to plot the `trace`:

```
pm.traceplot(trace[5000:])
```

And generate [posterior predictive samples](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/api.html#pymc3.sampling.sample_ppc):

```
ppc = pm.sample_ppc(trace[5000:], samples=500, model=model)
```

What I'm unsure of: **how do I ask questions of the model/posterior?**

For example, I'm assuming the distribution of scores for `Wales vs Italy` matchups would be:

```
# Wales vs Italy is the first matchup in our dataset
home_wales = ppc['home_points'][:, 0]
away_italy = ppc['away_points'][:, 0]
```

But what about matchups that aren't recorded in the original data?

- If Italy plays at home against France, what does their score distribution look like?
- If Italy plays at home against France, how often do both teams score under 15?

Thanks for any help/insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m fairly certain I was able to figure this out after reading through the [`PyMC3` Hierarchical Partial Pooling example](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/hierarchical_partial_pooling.html). Answering the questions in order:

1. Yes, that is what the distribution for `Wales vs Italy` matchups would be (since it’s the first game in the observed data).
2. In order to predict `Italy vs France` (since the two teams did not play against each other in our original dataset), we would need prediction `thetas`.

Here’s the code to the updated model:

```
# Setup the model similarly to the previous one...
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Global model parameters
    home = pm.Normal('home', 0, tau=.0001)
    tau_att = pm.Gamma('tau_att', .1, .1)
    tau_def = pm.Gamma('tau_def', .1, .1)
    intercept = pm.Normal('intercept', 0, tau=.0001)

    # Team-specific model parameters
    atts_star = pm.Normal('atts_star', mu=0, tau=tau_att, shape=num_teams)
    defs_star = pm.Normal('defs_star', mu=0, tau=tau_def, shape=num_teams)

    atts = pm.Deterministic('atts', atts_star - tt.mean(atts_star))
    defs = pm.Deterministic('defs', defs_star - tt.mean(defs_star))
    home_theta = tt.exp(intercept + home + atts[home_team] + defs[away_team])
    away_theta = tt.exp(intercept + atts[away_team] + defs[home_team])

    # Likelihood of observed data
    home_points = pm.Poisson('home_points', mu=home_theta, observed=observed_home_goals)
    away_points = pm.Poisson('away_points', mu=away_theta, observed=observed_away_goals)

# Now for predictions with no games played...
with model:
    # IDs from `teams` DataFrame
    italy, france = 4, 1
    # New `thetas` for Italy vs France predictions
    pred_home_theta = tt.exp(intercept + home + atts[italy] + defs[france])
    pred_away_theta = tt.exp(intercept + atts[france] + defs[italy])
    pred_home_points = pm.Poisson('pred_home_points', mu=pred_home_theta)
    pred_away_points = pm.Poisson('pred_away_points', mu=pred_away_theta)

# Sample the final model
with model:
    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.NUTS(state=start)
    trace = pm.sample(20000, step, init=start)
```

Once the `trace` is completed, we can plot the predictions:

```
# Use 5,000 as MCMC burn in
pred = pd.DataFrame({
    "italy": trace["pred_home_points"][5000:],
    "france": trace["pred_away_points"][5000:],
})
# Plot the distributions
sns.kdeplot(pred.italy, shade=True, label="Italy")
sns.kdeplot(pred.france, shade=True, label="France")
plt.show()
```

[image: Italy vs France Rugby distributions]

How often does Italy win at home?

```
# 19% of the time
(pred.italy > pred.france).mean()
```

How often do both teams score under 15?

```
# 0.7% of the time
1.0 * len(pred[(pred.italy <= 15) & (pred.france <= 15)]) / len(pred)
```

Comment: This looks good to me. Why don't you add it to the documentation of PyMC3?